# How should I handle testing of a Go function that uses runtime.GOOS?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing

I'm writing a Go package that needs to interact with the Linux command line. Since the CLI tools that my code is interacting with are Linux specific, I first need to make sure that the OS is Linux, and then I can check for the presence of the CLI tools.
My function to test the OS is as follows:

```
func isLinux() bool {
    return runtime.GOOS == "linux"
}
```

Realistically, the statement within the function can only return a boolean value. The result of the boolean being true or false seems to be wholly dependent on the testing environment too - so unless I run the tests across different OSes, I have to just assume that the function would return false in a Windows environment.

Is there a way for me to temporarily set the value of `runtime.GOOS` for the purpose of testing?

Would passing `runtime.GOOS` to the function as a string parameter be worthwhile? It would allow me to test the function more easily (because I could pass in string literals for different OSes), but since the function is so specific, and the snippet is so small, I'm not sure whether parameterising it would be worthwhile.

*EDIT:* It's more of a hypothetical question, I'm not really sure whether it's even worth testing given the size of the function. But, when I write code that's reliant on the current OS, how should I write it to facilitate testing - should I always to take the OS as a parameter so that I can easily mock it, or is there a way for me to temporarily override the value of `runtime.GOOS`?

Comment: What would a test for this function look like? I don't understand what you would try to test here.

Comment: I think unless there are very specific use (like having combination of `GOOS` and other build tag dependency like introduced by `cgo` or `GOARCH`), use build tag and have OS related code (including test) separated is better. Say, what sense does it make to test Linux related code on Windows?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I doubt that this snippet is even worth testing (although code coverage is always a bonus). My question isn't specific to this piece of code - really, what I'm asking is how should I deal with testing functions that rely on code that I can't easily mock. There's no easy way for me to override the value of `runtime.GOOS` , and short of running the tests across multiple platforms, I'm not sure how to manage testing something that relies on that value. I could refactor code to always take the OS as a parameter - but is that the best way to do it?

Comment: If you supplied the OS as a parameter and then tested that, you would effectively test the `==` operator, which I don't think is very useful.

Comment: @leafbebop the entire package is dependent on the CLI tool (it effectively acts as a wrapper around the functionality that the tool provides). My question is more to do with how I should go about testing code that changes behaviour depending on the OS, and whether there's an easy way to stub/mock it in tests - or whether I would have to test the package on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I handle testing of a Go function that uses runtime.GOOS?

Either not at all or on a machine with the appropriate OS.
It really is that simple.